# Move from one fragment to the other

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm developing a sapui5 fiori application, and i use a lot of fragments depending on the mode(read, create, edit). But i don't know how to navigate from one fragment to the other and especially how to return to the last fragment.
Any answer would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible to navigate to a fragment in routing because the loaded object will be instantiated with sap.ui.view which expects the given parameter to be a view instead of  a fragment. The fragment can be first instantiated and shown earliest in the ‘routeMatched’ handler.

Please also have a look at [Fragments](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/36a5b130076e4b4aac2c27eebf324909.html)

Comment: Yes, but it talks about moving from a view to another view not fragment...